# Using geterrmessage() in a loop - R

Tags: r, error-handling

My objective here is to capture the error that R throws and store it in an object.

Here are some dummy codes:

```
for(i in 1:length(a)){try(
if (i==4)(print(a[i]/"b"))else(print(a[i]/b[i]))
)}

[1] -0.125
[1] -0.2857143
[1] -0.5
Error in a[i]/"b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
[1] -1.25
[1] -2
[1] -3.5
[1] -8
[1] Inf
[1] 10
```

So I want to capture that on the 4th iteration the error was: `Error in a[i]/"b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator` into an object say:

```
error<-()
iferror(error[i]<-geterrmessage())
```

I am aware that iferror as a function is not available in R, but I am trying to give the idea, because `geterrmessage` captures only the last error it sees

So for the example i want say for `error[1:3]<-'NA'`and `error[5:10]<-'NA'` because no error but

```
error[4]<-"Error in a[i]/"b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

So that later I can check `error` object and understand where and what error happened

If you can help me write a code that would be excellent and highly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at `?tryCatch`? Might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following function helps:

```
a <- c(0:6)
b <- c(-3:3)

create_log <- function(logfile_name, save_path) {
  warning("Error messages not visible. Use closeAllConnections() in the end of the script")
  if (file.exists(paste0(save_path, logfile_name))) {
    file.remove(paste0(save_path, logfile_name))
  }
  fid <- file(paste0(save_path, logfile_name), open = "wt")
  sink(fid, type = "message", split = F) # warnings are NOT displayed. split=T not possible.
  sink(fid, append = T, type = "output", split = T) # print, cat
  return(NULL)
}


create_log("test.csv", "C:/Test/")
for(i in 1:length(a)){try(
  if (i==4)(print(a[i]/"b"))else(print(a[i]/b[i]))
)}
closeAllConnections()
```